# Сайт блокирует доступ парсеру

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Здравствуйте. Использую Simple HTML DOM Parser.
При попытке парсинга страницы ловлю ошибку:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2725145-kak-pravilno-pisat-nachisleny-ili-nachislenny.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Я думаю решить проблему подменой юзер агента или ip.

Вопрос: Как отправить подмененные параметры этим парсером?

Comment: Ip через него никак.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич а какие параметры им возможно подменить?

Comment: Обычно достаточно подменить user agent, для многих защит этого достаточно

Comment: @Денис **curl** вам в помощь

Comment: Интересно, на bolshoyvopros.ru кто-нибудь тоже задаёт вопрос, как обойти защиту stackoverflow?

Comment: @VladD впечатляет ваша репутация )) 153,520 !

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$base = 'http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2725145-kak-pravilno-pisat-nachisleny-ili-nachislenny.html';
$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html_base = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html_base->load($str); 

print_r( $html_base->plaintext );

$html_base->clear(); 
unset($html_base);

?>
```

*Если написать **$html_base->outertext** результат будет вот таким:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]